# Assembly error while using Model in MVC4 view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@using System.Data.Entity;

@model SurveyBuilderViewModel.SurveyViewModel



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "addQuestions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.QuestionModel.QuestionStatement);
```

It gives me error

```
The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

How can i fix it and where am i doing it wrong..????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is pretty clear

> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Reference that DLL in your project.